# How to take xpath for spinners which has same id & class in mobile automation(Appium)

Tags: appium

[image: image description here]

Since Parent Location2, Parent Location1, Location & Channel spinner has same id & class , how to get the xpath for the ParentLocation2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to xpath with indexes and nodes,
below are different examples for same:

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='8']")

//android.widget.RelativeLayout[8]
```